# Calculating a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, summation

$$  \sum_{x=1}^{2010 {1\over 2}} (4x^3 + x^2 + 2x  + 1)^{[7]} = ? $$

where $f(x)^{[n]}= f(x)f(x-1)\cdots f(x-n+1)$

2010 $1\over2$ = ${4021 \over 2}$

I couldn't compute this summation I would be glad if you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of $2010.5$ and $[7]$.

Comment: @vadim123 Sorry, I clarified it above.

Comment: It isn't really standart to have fractional values at the limits of summation. Perhaps you mean $2010$ or $2011$? If not, could you explain what a summation with rational endpoints even mean? Do you have a source of the problem?

Comment: $2010 \cdot \frac12 = 1005$, so just take your summation to 1005.

Comment: @Arkamis According to the question $2010\frac{1}{2}=\frac{4021}{2}\neq 1005$.

Comment: @Abel I see that now. What I thought was a small dot was just some dirt on my screen. Cleaning the dirt of my screen, unfortunately, doesn't make the rest of the question make any sense.

Comment: @IanMateus Why not have a fraction at the end point ? I mean are there any counterexamples of not having fractions on the limits of a summation ?

Comment: You could put anything at your enpoints. But you would still have to explain what it means, since this is by no means usual in the context of a summation over what I assume to be integers. But even that is not clear, now.

Comment: @julien here is an example for you with fractions. Same logic different function for summation. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163449/fractions-in-limits-of-a-summation

Comment: Where did you see this problem?

Comment: @JESUS It is unusual to see a summation with rational endpoints that are not integers. Writing $\sum_{k=0}^{1.34}k$ is simply meaningless, unless you define it to be something, i.e. give a new meaning to that "sum". The notation $\sum_{k=a}^b f(k)$ means by default $f(a)+f(a+1)+\cdots+f(b)$ and this interpretation is not possible in $\mathbb{Q}$. If you can interpret it somehow, you can tell what it would mean, though. Nothing stops you from creating new interpretations (but please tell us...)

Comment: In this case, if your top is $2010.5$, please replace it by $2010$ as it does not make any difference.

Comment: @JESUS You can see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_summation_formula some examples where $x$ is not natural number, BUT, here, we know when to stop, because $n$ is integer. This is standard in analytic number theory.

Comment: @Cortizol today a student of mine asked it. I took the question with me.

Comment: @julien replacing it with 2010 will basically change the answer too much. But if you are comfortable with 2010 try with that.

Comment: The integers in $[0,2010]$ are the same as the integers in $[0,2010.5]$. So there is absolutely no difference (interpreting what the sum means from what you linked).